# jQueryMobile page transition functionality broken

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition

I am building a cross-platform app using jQueryMobile and Phonegap. Currently using jQM 1.1.0 and Phonegap 1.6.1.

The page transition function sometimes just seems to break down when the user clicks a button or list item that links to another page in the app.

```
<a href="#page2">
```

This kind of link is what the whole app is made of. But depending on god knows what, sometimes when you click a link the app stalls. External links will still be followed, and buttons that don't trigger any page changing work fine. But anything with href and $.mobile.changePage seems to be broken.

This problem occurs in iPad Simulator and iPhone Simulator, not in Chrome. It seems to have something to do with the type of page transition specified (i.e. fade or slide or flip etc). Some transitions seem to cause problems, sometimes it seems to be the lack of a specified transition that is the cause, and sometimes neither of those explanations have any traction.

Before I add a whole bunch of code, I'm interested if anyone has similar experiences.